# Can i host my mobile app on a physical server

Tags: flutter, mobile, mobile-application

I have a physical server I would like to know if it is possible to deploy my mobile application on this server?

Answer (score 0):

Mobile application runs on the device itself, you are either talking about a webpage or a backend server.

Answer (score 0):

App hosting allows you to run the backend on servers or in the cloud hosted by a service provider such as Amazon Web Services (AWS)